# make rule that invokes another rule several times with different values for a variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a rule `something`, that works on the variable `VAR`. I also have another rule `something-all`, that needs to run `something`, with `VAR` set to each value in `vars`.

```
vars = hello world

something:
    echo $(VAR)

something-all:
    $(foreach VAR,$(vars),something)
```

This doesn't quite work, I get

```
noob@work:~/Desktop$ make something-all
something something
make: something: No such file or directory
make: *** [something-all] Error 1
```

It should probably print `hello\nworld`.

I used to do this with wildcard rules by retrieving `VAR` from `%`, but got the feeling that was the wrong way to do it. This looked like this:

```
vars = hello world

all: $(foreach VAR,$(vars),something-$(VAR))

something-%:
    echo $*
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "wildcard rules" approach? You might be describing the solution that occurs to me, but you might not.

Comment: Thx @Beta I've added this.

Comment: @Beta See now, thanks

Comment: So you don't want to use pattern rules. And what do you mean by "canonical"?

Comment: @Beta: I'd accept as canonical anything a fancy/advanced user of GNU Make would use, such as automake, and/but still human-readable.

Comment: Then just use a pattern rule, there's nothing wrong with them, advanced users use them all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below should fix your problem

**Using foreach** (Tried on GNU Make 3.80 on sparc-solaris 2.8 and windows)

```
vars = hello world

something:
    echo $(VAR)

something-all:
    $(foreach i, $(vars), $(MAKE) something VAR=$i || exit 1;)
```

**Using shell for-loop** (Tried on GNU Make 3.80 and cc make on sparc-solaris 2.8)

```
vars = hello world

something:
    echo $(VAR)

something-all:
    for i in $(vars); do $(MAKE) something VAR=$$i || exit 1; done
```

Comment: In the number 2, you need to add `|| exit 1` after the make invocation, so that the error from sub-make is propagated. See also my comment to Jens' answer: in the number 1 you ignore all make errors except the last one.

Comment: @Dummy00001 Thanks. I have updated the answer. As the OP did not ask for it, I did not include that in the sample; but OP might have just overlooked it.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR: If you want to program make, drop GNU Make in favor of BSD Make.**

This is a personal recommendation. While BSD Make seems more limited than GNU Make, as it offers less programming facilities, it is [much easier to program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131219/merits-of-bmake/26503692#26503692) and has a [few unique killer features](https://www.bsdcan.org/2014/schedule/attachments/267_freebsd-bmake-slides.pdf).  This is why I propose a solution with GNU Make and another solution for BSD Make:

### Doing it in GNU Make

Using GNU Make, you can [write a macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Functions.html#Functions) to define a target.  The canonical way to define a sequence in a Makefile is to add the steps of the sequence as dependencies to a target, as reflected by the snippet below:

```
vars= hello world

define something_t =
something: something-$(1)
something-$(1):
    @echo $(1)
endef

$(foreach _,$(vars),$(eval $(call something_t,$_)))
```

It is recommended to use this organisation (rather than defining just one target), because you can work on it to make the task easily resumable if you interrupt the sequence. A Makefile [describes a job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026331/what-is-the-purpose-of-creating-object-files-separately-and-then-linking-them-to/26027691#26027691) whose advancement is entirely described by the state of the file system. A task is then easily resumable, if each step is associated to a file, usually a compilation object but sometimes also an empty file which is touch'ed to indicate that important checkpoints have been passed.

Using an auxiliary macro is a flexible solution that can be adapted to more complicated tasks than just echoing a name. Note that this does work with newest versions of GNU Make (4.1). On GNU Make 3.81, you should remove the equal sign from the macro definition.

### Adapting your example for BSD Make

If this is an option for you, I recommand dropping the use of GNU Make and replace it by BSD Make, which is [way easier to program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131219/merits-of-bmake/26503692#26503692): it [has a short and to the point documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make(1)), while the documentation of GNU Make is very verbose and somewhat unclear, BSD Make has industrial-strength examples of complex rulesets ([FreeBSD Build system](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/share/mk/) or [BSD Owl](https://github.com/michipili/bsdowl)), and it has a simple and predictable macro language.

```
vars= hello world

something:
.for _var in ${vars}
    echo ${_var}
.endfor
```

This can evolve to support more complicated tasks, just by replacing the `echo` by the adapted commands, or using intermediary steps.

### Allow the user to override some tasks, also in BSD Make

In this slightly more advanced variation, we allow the user to override our own recipes for building targets `something-hello` and `something-world`.
For each item in our list, a target `something-*` is created it if it does not already exist, and added to the dependencies of `something`. The whole operation of defining these targets only happens if `something` has been left undefined.  Therefore, users of these macros can:

1. Override the recipes for `something-hello` and `something-world`
2. Override the full procedure bound to `something`.

Implementing such customisation possibilities is mandatory if we want to write useful, reusable, macros for Make. Unluckily, customisation of this sort is [nearly impossible in GNU Make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815057/how-to-programmatically-define-targets-in-gnu-make).

```
vars = hello world

.if!target(depend)
.for _var in ${vars}
.if!target(something-${_var})
something-${_var}:
    echo ${_var}
.endif
something: something-${_var}
.endfor
.endif
```

Comment: IIRC dropping the = from the syntax will make it work on older versions of GNU make as well.

Comment: @hkBst I just gave it a try. You are right, indeed!

Comment: Just an additional note: if using niche software is not an issue, omake is one of the most advanced make utilities. http://omake.metaprl.org

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, on Debian-based systems the BSD make is available as `bmake` (previously as `pmake`).

Comment: "Doing it in GNU Make". I have tested the trick and it is useless, since `$(eval)` forces premature evaluation of the variables like `$@`/`$<`/etc. To make it usable one has to add additional layer(s) of recursive make invocation (iow even more mess).

Comment: @Dummy00001 This is one of the various reasons why I avoid to use GNU Make and prefer BSD Make (usually `bmake`) over it, as it is [much easier to program](https://github.com/michipili/bsdowl).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
VARS := hello world
THINGS := $(addprefix something-, $(VARS))

allthings: $(THINGS)

something-%:
    echo $*
```

Comment: ... have you just plagiarized piece of question and put it up as your own answer? The OP has already that, he asks if there is anything better.

Comment: No I'm pretty sure that's the solution I said I didn't want.

Answer (score 1):

It should be no surprise that

```
vars := hello world
something-all:
    $(foreach VAR,$(vars),something)
```

tries to run `something something`. That's exactly what the `foreach` expands to, *since you don't reference `VAR` in the third expression*.

All you need to do is **reference `VAR` and use a command** such as `echo`:

```
vars := hello world
something-all:
    $(foreach VAR,$(vars),echo $(VAR);)

$ make
echo hello; echo world;
hello
world
```

Note how chaining the commands with a semicolon avoids forking several shells or -- **GASP!** -- recursive `make` invocations. It doesn't get more performant than that.

Alternatively, if your command accepts several somethings as arguments,

```
vars := hello world
something-all:
    echo $(foreach VAR,$(vars),$(VAR))

$ make
echo hello world
hello world
```

But that is equivalent to the super simple `echo $(vars)`. So it might pay off to think outside the box trying to change your requirements to make this simple solution work.

Comment: In the first code, replace the `;` with `&&` and add in the end the `true` - and it is pretty much what I often use myself. Gotchas is that it negates the parallelization.

Comment: @Dummy00001 Reading your comment feels like reading oneself mind. :)